# What are thread names used for in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I find that each thread has its own name such as **`Thread-1`**, **`Thread-2`** and **`test_thread`** as shown below:

```py
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=test)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=test, name="test_thread")

print(thread1.name) # "Thread-1"
print(thread2.name) # "Thread-2"
print(thread3.name) # "test_thread"
```

But, I cannot find why each thread has its own name.

So, what are thread names used for?

Comment: Thread name is [a string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name)

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name):

> A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple threads may be given the same name.

Other libraries could have an use for a thread's name (and you can get it with `threading.currentThread().name`), even if the computer doesn't care.

E.g. `logging` supports `%(threadName)s`, so you can log which thread is emitting a message; that could be useful in a program which e.g. downloads things in one thread and dispatches other threads to process items, or whatever.